# How to mute phone completely but keep watch's notifications vibrate?

Tags: notifications, audio, vibration, android-wear

I have and android phone and an android wear watch (specifically, LG G3 and sony swr50).

If I get all the notifications on the watch, I prefer my phone to be completely muted - not ring, nor vibrate.

BUT, when trying to mute everything on the phone, the watch gets muted as well - everything gets into `no interruption mode`.

**Is there a way to mute the phone completely (sound and vibration) but still have vibrations on the watch?**

Answer (score 2):

There is an option in the Android Wear app to mute your phone when the watch is connected. This will mute your phone (even stop it from vibrating) but your watch will vibrate (for all notifs that would normally vibrate on your phone).

BUT: there has been a bug since forever where the watch suddenly starts buzzing again. It works *most* of the time though..

Answer (score 0):

Found a way. Use an empty ringtone and notification mp3 sound file.

Also, set the phone to not vibrate on calls and notifications.

This way the phone plays the sound but it just plays the empty ringtone and the watch vibrates - Singe point of indication!!!

Comment: Example of such an empty ringtone: http://www.jetcityorange.com/silent-ringtone/silence-1sec.mp3